# Long link when I redirect to index

Tags: laravel

I have the following form:

```
<form action="/compras" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select class="form-control" id="productor" name="productor">
                    <option value="0">Selecciona Productor</option>
                    @foreach ($productores as $productor)
                    <option value="{{$productor->id}}">{{$productor->nombre}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm 6">
                <select class="form-control" id="proveedor" name="proveedor">
                    <option value="0">Selecciona Proveedor</option>
                    @foreach ($proveedores as $proveedor)
                    <option value="{{$proveedor->id}}">{{$proveedor->nombre}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-secondary mr-2" name="action" value="search" type="submit">Buscar</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" name="action" value="create" type="submit">Crear</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I don't actually need to save data to the database in this controller, however I used the `store` function because of the `post` route that it includes. The idea is that if you press the `Buscar` button it will redirect to index filtering the table with the parameters, if you press `Crear` button it will redirect to a different controller and do something different

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        switch($request->input('action')){
            case 'create':
                return Redirect::action('ComprandoController@index', array('productor'=> $request->productor, 'proveedor'=>$request->proveedor));
            break;

            case 'search': 
                return Redirect::action('ComprasController@index', $request);
            break;
        }

    }
```

The code is working as intended but when I redirect to index I have a problem in the link.

The link before filtering is: `127.0.0.1:4545/compras` but after the filter it's something like

```
http://127.0.0.1:4545/compras?POST%20/compras%20HTTP/1.1%0D%0AAccept:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8%0D%0AAccept-Encoding:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20gzip,%20deflate%0D%0AAccept-Language:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3%0D%0AConnection:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20keep-alive%0D%0AContent-Length:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2085%0D%0AContent-Type:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20application/x-www-form-urlencoded%0D%0ACookie:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IlhvQkVGa2libnlydUcyRDNQVElRdlE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZWh0d091RUphUE9BV0t0dUtjY2w0akw4VEx2TjkxaVIySXFKWmpJbkVueVU5cHpHZXgvQ3l0TGc0U28zNFAwNSIsIm1hYyI6IjEzMDk3NTI5MWRjOTI2Nzg3YjA4ZWNiYTVlODZjN2ZjMGJjMWFjNWRkNjRjNjcwNDYwOWI5YjBjODE3NmRkMWUifQ%3D%3D;%20laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IkFCcGR2d01xZmwwbmh4dGprMGNYZHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVHI1aGUzWjVTdlgyVVE3WmFGV01PSjhTb01ZTWxnVllEL2Q2SmVxQ1BpVW5qY24yZjlLc01pdUVRNjNoRDEyTiIsIm1hYyI6ImFkNDI3NzBjZmUwZmRmZmE5ZDM2NjM1YTBkMWQyZjM2ZTUwOTQ4NjcwNzlhNGJkNzJhYjFlNTI1NjE5OTZjOWIifQ%3D%3D%0D%0AHost:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20127.0.0.1:4545%0D%0AOrigin:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20http://127.0.0.1:4545%0D%0AReferer:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20http://127.0.0.1:4545/compras?POST%20/compras%20HTTP/1.1%0D%0AAccept:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8%0D%0AAccept-Encoding:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20gzip,%20deflate%0D%0AAccept-Language:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3%0D%0AConnection:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20keep-alive%0D%0AContent-Length:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2085%0D%0AContent-Type:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20application/x-www-form-urlencoded%0D%0ACookie:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkpNVTA3dDk1cDZlSUhYNUorRndkamc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiK1JXTVFyN2dFcHJLaC9uK1QzMjhjQ1FTa2ZuQzFCM1FabnpiY3lXbzZPMzdVbGE2c0w2b3dWSlp5YnpMdVc0VyIsIm1hYyI6IjRhOTdjNTJiMTA1ODI2ODRmMDVhOTgyMDg1NTMxMzY1YzhiNTI2MGJhMzk1YzZjMzBhNTg5YmJhNDY0N2YzZDYifQ%3D%3D;%20laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImU4bUUxenZUR0RCaTBJZis4WTg4TGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiYkxucWdXNi81YmlvNzRUbjlqSEpxdUt3ZnBiazVxYURCaVBXSFYwbXZPU0hxTk1Sa2RFSDJVTkIyZUdHVTNGeSIsIm1hYyI6ImFmYWVjMjM1NmMwYTljMjkzNGQ4MmFlYjIwY2Q3MzJhMzI1OTY4MjUwM2ZkZmRhZmIyNTBjNmJiZjYxZDQ1NWQifQ%3D%3D%0D%0AHost:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20127.0.0.1:4545%0D%0AOrigin:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20http://127.0.0.1:4545%0D%0AReferer:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20http://127.0.0.1:4545/%0D%0AUpgrade-Insecure-Requests:%201%0D%0AUser-Agent:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Mozilla/5.0%20%28Windows%20NT%2010.0;%20Win64;%20x64;%20rv:80.0%29%20Gecko/20100101%20Firefox/80.0%0D%0ACookie:%20XSRF-TOKEN=fBi5Ch1lKRYNMLswqGIkUc94OOTjNTa8aNMmZ7h5;%20laravel_session=eV6iavmA0PGGAkisR1egs2mLHqbW6w9j58maOxDC%0D%0A%0D%0A_token=fBi5Ch1lKRYNMLswqGIkUc94OOTjNTa8aNMmZ7h5&productor=0&proveedor=0&action=search%0D%0AUpgrade-Insecure-Requests:%201%0D%0AUser-Agent:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Mozilla/5.0%20%28Windows%20NT%2010.0;%20Win64;%20x64;%20rv:80.0%29%20Gecko/20100101%20Firefox/80.0%0D%0ACookie:%20XSRF-TOKEN=fBi5Ch1lKRYNMLswqGIkUc94OOTjNTa8aNMmZ7h5;%20laravel_session=eV6iavmA0PGGAkisR1egs2mLHqbW6w9j58maOxDC%0D%0A%0D%0A_token=fBi5Ch1lKRYNMLswqGIkUc94OOTjNTa8aNMmZ7h5&productor=1&proveedor=3&action=search
```

How could I get rid of the grotesque big link without ruining the working code?

Comment: if you don't save anything! why don't you just put an A tag with a route in the href

Comment: @Snoxik true, let me try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add your route file ?

I prefer use `return redirect()->route('route.name', ['id' => 1]);` to do redirect from controller.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/redirects#redirecting-named-routes

Also, you can use `$request->all()` or `$request->only(['productor', 'proveedor'])`.

PS : the link is long, because Laravel serialize all datas from `$request`.